# Monodroid designer is missing device configurations

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

Monodroid designer was working until yesterday, now it has lost the preconfigured list of device configurations and I have no idea how to get them back. Before this occurred the only system change I think may be related was that I tried updating the Android SDK and platform tools, which may have failed once, but retried and now they are both updated ok. Perhaps this made monodroid designer loose these configurations. I open Monodevelop and the designer is the also missing them. Has anyone seen this happen or know how to restore them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to Mono for Android 4.4.38

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me after the update.

You need to completely uninstall the Android SDK and Mono for Android and reinstall them.

Comment: I did this and it made no difference? Does anyone at xamarin know how to manually fix this. This is a serious problem and is holding me back. When you reintalled the SDK, did you let monodroid installer brind down the latest or did you install the older one again manually?

Comment: update: Xamarin acknowledged it is a bug and will be fixed. I restored my SDK folder from backup to get it working again.

Comment: @mdev did they say what was wrong? I have the same problem, except that I removed my android backup folder completely.

Comment: They didn't but I got a message to say its suppose to be fixed in the latest beta channel release, so I'm trying it today. MonoDevelop 3.0.6 for MonoDevelop users or Android 4.4.38